# toggle button, but toggle only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a nice code for a audio play-button. After clicking it becomes a pause-button. That's fine, but I want to keep it a pause button. So it should toggle only once. Would be nice to add some code, and not replacing by completely new code. The code:

```
<script>
function a(el){
play()
}

function b(el){
pause()
}

$(".btn-play").click(function() {
  var el = this;
  return (el.t = !el.t) ? a(el) : b(el);
 }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML and CSS.

Comment: `el.t = !el.t` is an assignment, it always returns true

Comment: @Pascamel no - it will always be the result of the assignment, not always true.  `var x = true;
alert((x=!x) ? "true" : "false")
var x = false;
alert((x=!x) ? "true" : "false")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather general answer for "I want to use the button only once", as there isn't much detail given in the question.

You can disable the button with  `$('.btn-play').attr("disabled", true)` or `$(".btn-play").unbind("click")` - just make sure this picks only the button you want.

If you want the button to then have different functionality (pause instead of play or something) I would suggest defining handlers separately, so you can use `.unbind("click", handler1)` followed by `.bind("click", handler2)` or in some other way keep the two handlers separate, [as per documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `el.t == false` means `b()`, simply add a pre-check:

```
$(".btn-play").click(function() {
  var el = this;
  if (!el.t) b(el);
  return (el.t = !el.t) ? a(el) : b(el);
});
```

if you mean it to be the other, then use `if (el.t) b(el);`

Personally, I'd simplify the code:

```
$(".btn-play").click(function() {
  var el = this;
  if (!el.t) b(el);
  el.t = false;
  a(el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this: https://jsfiddle.net/e0evwnvu/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isPauseButton = false;
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    if (!isPauseButton) {
        play();
      isPauseButton = true;
    } else {
        pause();
    }
  });
});

function play() {
    alert('play');
}

function pause() {
    alert('pause');
}
```